# Getting errors when trying to create a function that uses protocols and generics

Tags: ios, xcode, generics, swift

I have a class that intends to return a class which conforms to `PanelControllerProtocol`. The problem I'm having is taking the anyClass object and converting it to T.

```
func classFromBundle<T: PanelControllerProtocol>(className: String) -> T {
    let bundleClassString = classBundleAndName(className)
    var anyClass : AnyClass = NSClassFromString(bundleClassString)
}
```

If I try this:

```
var panelControllerType = anyClass as T
```

I get:

> "Cannot cast from concrete type 'AnyClass' to type variable 'T' for
>   which it does not match constraints".

Attempting to simply return `anyClass` gives me the error:

> 'AnyClass' is not convertible to 'T'

Trying to change my method name to this:

```
func classFromBundle<T where T: AnyClass, T: PanelControllerProtocol>(className: String) -> T
```

Gives the error:

> Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol type 'AnyClass'

Also, once I figure out how to return the correct object, I'm not sure how to call the class. Currently, calling the above method like so:

```
classFromBundle("Test")
```

Gives the error:

> Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSString' to type 'String'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
var instance: AnyObject? = NSClassFromString(bundleClassString)
let actualClassInstance = instance as T

return actualClassInstance
```

but, as you might guess, if the class type is not found, that generates a runtime exception.

A better solution is to let your function return an optional `T`, and account for `NSClassFromString` to fail creating an instance of the `T` class:

```
var actualClassInstance: T?

var instance: AnyObject? = NSClassFromString(bundleClassString)

if instance != nil {
    actualClassInstance = instance as? T
}

return actualClassInstance
```

Note that `NSClassFromString`, accordingly to the documentation:

> Returns: The class object named by aClassName, or nil if no class by that name is currently loaded.

is returning the wrong type `AnyObject!`, whereas it should be `AnyObject?`

To call the function, you just have to tell the compiler what `T` is - and you do it by inferring the type from the variable the function result is assigned to:

```
let concreteClass: ConcreteClass = classFromBundle("ConcreteClass")
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                   This tells the compiler what T is
```

If you are using the 2nd (safer) version of the code, then you should declare the variable as optional:

```
let concreteClass: ConcreteClass? = classFromBundle("ConcreteClass")
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for your question?